# Print Any Older Version of the Queue

Tags: algorithm

I came across this question and thought of asking what is the best possible way to achieve this.

Given a FIFO queue. you can assume that queue contains integers. Every time an insertion or deletion happens, a new version of the queue is created. At any time, you have to print(whole content of the queue) any older version of the queue with minimal time and space complexity.

Comment: Your question is too open-ended.  What info do you need to track?  Are you just interested in the queue length over time, or do you want to maintain info about the specific set of entities in the queue at any point in time? If the latter who has allocation/deletion privileges for those entities, i.e., can you just maintain a set of references or do you need to clone them to make sure you can still reconstruct the queue if they've been deallocated elsewhere?  Finally, in line with stackoverflow expectations, what have you tried?

Comment: @pjs The question is very precise.  It is not his fault that you are unable to read a clear description, and insist on creating new requirements that are not there.

Comment: @btilly The question is not precise if I need to make assumptions when I consider possible implementations.  I work with queueing models all the time, and in some scenarios you're only interested in how many entities are present, while at other times you need to know their individual specifics.

Comment: @pjs: I agree you could ask, what he has tried but the problem itself is very neat and it's an easy problem both to understand and solve. By **print any older version of the queue**, it's clear you've to print **the queue**, all its contents of course.

Comment: @Fallen: I disagree with your "of course". With the models I deal with, entities in a queue are often objects with extensive storage requirements.  If I can assume that they're not disposed elsewhere, then I can get away with keeping references to them.  If there's no guarantee that they won't be disposed of or altered, I have to clone them. This affects the space complexity, an explicit part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is assuming you meant a FIFO queue and not some other kind of queue, like a priority queue.

Store it in an array and keep two pointer variables, one to its head and another to its tail.

For example:

```
insert 3 2 5 9 - version 1
q = [3 2 5 9]
     ^     ^
delete, delete - version 2
q = [3 2 5 9]
         ^ ^
insert 6 3 4 - version 3
q = [3 2 5 9 6 3 4]
         ^       ^
```

To print a version, you just need to store two values for each version: where the pointers were. Printing is then linear in the size of the queue at that version.

The vector can grow big, but you have to store every element there ever was in it if you want to be able to print any version.

You can also use a linked list to avoid array resizing if you consider that a problem. Just make sure not to remove a node from memory when deleting.

Comment: This is the best solution for average amortized performance.  It might not be appropriate for real time code because occasional resizing operations on the array can be `O(n)`.

Comment: @btilly - a linked list could still be used, as long as you don't need full random access and don't actually delete the head when doing a removal. No resizing then, just some memory overhead.

Comment: Yes, your solution could reasonably be done with a linked list as well.  However "find an old version" should be something more efficient than "search a linked list".

Comment: @btilly - you wouldn't search anything. You would, for each version, store a pointer to that version's head and tail. So finding an old version would involve iterating the nodes between two pointers.

Comment: The search I was referring to is "find the version at time X".

Comment: @btilly - me too. Finding it is `O(1)` and printing it is linear in its size, since I store pointers to where in the linked list it starts.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is to make the queue a partially persistent data structure.

Partially persistent means that you can query any version, but you only can make updates in the most recent version.

A couple years ago I've given a speech about making any pointer data structure persistent. It was based on ["Making data structures persistent"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/making-data-structures-persistent.pdf) by Driscoll, Sarnak, Sleator and Tarjan.

Clearly, any queue can be implemented as a linked data structure. If you want the simplest practical version, you may be interested in method called "The Fat Node Method" which is described on page 91 in the above PDF.

The idea is to store in every node several pointers to the next elements corresponding to different versions of the queue. Each pointer has assigned a version number called timestamp.

For every insert or delete operation, you update pointers only in nodes touched by the update operation.

For lookup operation in the `i-th` version of the queue, you simply follow the pointers with the largest timestamp not exceeding `i`. You can find the pointer to follow using the binary search.

In the given PDF there is also a more complex, but also even more efficient method called "The Node-Copying Method".

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions.  Here is one with all operations guaranteed `O(log(n))` and normal operations an amortized `O(log(log(n))`.

Keep an operation counter.  Store the items in a skip list (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list for a definition of that) based on the order of the insertion operation.  When an element is removed, fill in the id of the removal operation.  For efficiency of access, keep a pair of pointers to the current head and current tail.

To insert an element, add it to the current tail.  To return an element, return it to the current head.  To return a past state, search the skip list for the then head, then start walking the list until you read the then tail.

The `log(n)` operations here are finding the past head, and (very occasionally) inserting a new head that happens to be a high node in the skip list.

Answer (score 0):

Now lets us assume that in a FIFO queue, the head pointer is at the beginning of the array, and then the tail pointer is at the end of the current insertion. Then by storing the current tail position pointer value in a variable which is used as the head pointer position during future insertion and tail position again takes the end of that insertion. This way just by using a single variable and with only insertion taking place, previous versions can be printed from the beginning of the array to the tail pointer.

```
insert 3 2 1 4
a=[3 2 1 4]  --version 1    
   ^     ^ 
   b     e
p = e;


insert 5 7 8
a=[3 2 1 4 5 7 8] --version 2    
           ^   ^
           b   e
here version 1 = position 0 to position p = [3 2 1 4]
p = e;

delete 3
a=[2 1 4 5 7 8] --version 3    
         ^   ^
         b   e
here version 2 = position 0 to position p =[2 1 4 7 8]

where
b = beginning 
e = end
```

Hence by using a single variable to hold previous version tail position and assuming the beginning position to be always 0 , previous versions can be easily printed.